# Where was Mujadid and Imam Mahdi in the 14th century?

Tags: imam-mahdi

As said in different hadeeths that [Imam Mahdi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahdi) was suppose to come in 14th century (Islamic calendar) but where is it and can someone give me reference to that hadeeth.

Also there is one hadeeth which points out that Allah send Mujadid in start of every century is that hadith authentic.

> حَدَّثَنَا سُلَيْمَانُ بْنُ دَاوُدَ الْمَهْرِيُّ، أَخْبَرَنَا ابْنُ
> وَهْبٍ، أَخْبَرَنِي سَعِيدُ بْنُ أَبِي أَيُّوبَ، عَنْ شَرَاحِيلَ بْنِ
> يَزِيدَ الْمَعَافِرِيِّ، عَنْ أَبِي عَلْقَمَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ،
> فِيمَا أَعْلَمُ عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏
> إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَبْعَثُ لِهَذِهِ الأُمَّةِ عَلَى رَأْسِ كُلِّ مِائَةِ
> سَنَةٍ مَنْ يُجَدِّدُ لَهَا دِينَهَا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو دَاوُدَ
> رَوَاهُ
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: **Allah will raise for this community at the end
> of every hundred years the one who will renovate its religion for it**.
> Abu Dawud said: 'Abd al-Rahman bin Shuriah al-Iskandarani has also
> transmitted this tradition, but he did not exceed Shrahil.

Grade: Sahih (Al-Albani)
Reference: Sunan Abi Dawud 4291
In-book reference: Book 39, Hadith 1 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/39))

Hadith which states coming of Imam Mahdi in 14th century:

> حَدَّثَنَا الْحَسَنُ بْنُ عَلِيٍّ الْخَلاَّلُ، حَدَّثَنَا عَوْنُ بْنُ
> عُمَارَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ الْمُثَنَّى بْنِ ثُمَامَةَ
> بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ أَنَسٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ جَدِّهِ، عَنْ
> أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ أَبِي قَتَادَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ
> ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ
>
> الآيَاتُ بَعْدَ الْمِائَتَيْنِ
>
> It was narrated from Anas bin Malik that Abu Qatadah said: “The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “The signs (will come) after two hundred (years).’ (Sunan Ibn Maja hadith #4057; [sunnah.com](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1291570))

**NOTE**
200 years in reality refer to they are after a specific time of 1000 years since the word in the hadith uses “Mi’atain” which means 200, along with the definite article of “al”

**As Hazrat Mullah Ali Qari stated:**

> Perhaps the definite article Al in the word al-mi’atain refers to that
> period of 200 years as well following 1000 years (meaning 1200) and
> this is the time of the advent of the Mahdi as well” (Mishkat
> Mujtaba’i, Page 471 Footnote and Ibni Majah Volume 2, Page 21 footnote
> by Allamah Sindhi)

Comment: If the hadith is based on sunni tradition whom this person could be or have been will be concluded afterwards.

Comment: I have added the reference to the hadith

Comment: Relevant questions http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12487/sunni-viewpoint-about-vasi-or-hojjat-in-each-era (take also a look at my linked Wikipedia site in my comment here) and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29305/what-is-sunni-view-regarding-the-savior-of-the-world

Comment: I've never heard such a hadith saying that al-mahdi would come in the 14th century. The Arabic wikipedia site suggestes for the 14th century: محمد متولي الشعراوي (1329هـ - 1419هـ) Sheikh a-Sha'arawi, al-Albaniمحمد ناصر الدين الألباني (1333هـ - 1420هـ) , Ahmad Deedat أحمد ديدات (1336هـ - 1426هـ) and Mustafa Mahmoud مصطفى محمود (1340هـ - 1430هـ) I'd prefere to add الطاهر ابن عاشور https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Tahir_ibn_Ashur and sheikh al-Ghazali محمد الغزالي السقا https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammed_al-Ghazali.

Comment: As Hazrat Isa is suppose to come in 14th century according to ullama's. So in another hadith its mentioned that he(Isa (as)) will pray behind Mahdi. So one can conclude that they will come around same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40490/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-user606669).

Comment: @Medi1Saif  any thoughts I've added the 14th century reference as well, in which Imam mahdi was suppose to come.