# Is the translation for word hakam as ruler in hadith correct?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, prophet-isa, last-day

The translator has chosen ruler for word hakam. Is this correct?

حَدَّثَنَا عَلِيُّ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ، حَدَّثَنَا الزُّهْرِيُّ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي سَعِيدُ بْنُ الْمُسَيَّبِ، سَمِعَ أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ لاَ تَقُومُ السَّاعَةُ حَتَّى يَنْزِلَ فِيكُمُ ابْنُ مَرْيَمَ حَكَمًا مُقْسِطًا، فَيَكْسِرَ الصَّلِيبَ، وَيَقْتُلَ الْخِنْزِيرَ، وَيَضَعَ الْجِزْيَةَ، وَيَفِيضَ الْمَالُ حَتَّى لاَ يَقْبَلَهُ أَحَدٌ ‏"‏‏.‏

Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "The Hour will not be established until the son of Mary (i.e. Jesus) descends amongst you as a just ruler, he will break the cross, kill the pigs, and abolish the Jizya tax. Money will be in abundance so that nobody will accept it (as charitable gifts).

Sahih al-Bukhari 2476
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2476.

Two people were arguing that jesus will lead prayer from dhuhr because he will be amir ul mumineen. Another said mahdi will continue as amir ul mumineen even after coming of eesa.

Mahdi will lead fajr is unanimously accepted by all when Jesus prays first fajr during his second coming. Hence im asking does the hadith prove will jesus be amir ul mumineen?

Comment: Could you explain what the issue you have with it or what led you to doubt the translation?

Comment: First the hadith doesn't call him Hakim, but Hakam. Secondly in the translation of Sahih Muslim it also apprars as "judge".

Comment: @The Z ,@Medi1Saif, have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some sahih sources of this hadith

The question is not that easy to answer.
There are a few similar narrations in both Sahih's

- In Sahih al-Bukhari: In the book of [oppressions](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2476), in the book of [Sayings and teachings of the prophets](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3448) and in the book of [sales and trades](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2222)
- In Sahih Muslim: In the book of faith [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:155a) and [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:155b).

### Meanings from linguistic perspective

In Arabic the noun:

> حَكَم (*hakam*)

refers to a referee, arbitrator, judge, it may also apply as a ruler and this is how it is translated in some of the translations of Sahih Muslim.
While:

> حَاكِم (Haakim)

usually refers to a ruler, a leader and may also apply as referee, judge, arbitrator.

### Commentaries on the specific hadith

Ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani said commenting this hadith in the chapter "Sayings and teachings of the prophets()" in his Fath al-Bary -see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=2077&bk_no=52&idfrom=6275&idto=6278) in Arabic-:
 <sup>In the following I'll be translating from Arabic language, as these translations are of my own take them carefully.</sup>

> ( حكما ) أي حاكما ، والمعنى أنه ينزل حاكما بهذه الشريعة فإن هذه الشريعة باقية لا تنسخ ، بل يكون عيسى حاكما من حكام هذه الأمة .
> (Hakam) means a ruler, and the meaning is that he descends as a ruler with this shari'a, for this shari'a will remain and will not be abrogated, rather 'Isa will be the ruler of the rulers of this nation.
>
> وفي رواية الليث عن ابن شهاب عند مسلم " حكما مقسطا " وله من طريق ابن عيينة عن ابن شهاب " إماما مقسطا " والمقسط العادل بخلاف القاسط فهو الجائر .
> And in the narration of Al-Layth on the authority of ibn Shihab in <sup>the book of</sup>  Muslim, "a just judge," and it has a path via ibn 'Uyaynah on the authority of Ibn Shihab “a just imam. (leader)”
>
> ولأحمد من وجه آخر عن أبي هريرة أقرئوه من رسول الله السلام وعند أحمد من حديث عائشة ويمكث عيسى في الأرض أربعين سنة وللطبراني من حديث عبد الله بن مغفل ينزل عيسى ابن مريم مصدقا بمحمد على ملته
> And <sup>it was narrated by</sup> Ahmad from another route on the authority of Abu Huraira, who had read it <sup>(or been informed)</sup> (from others) from the Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him, and according to Ahmad from the hadith of 'Aisha, that 'Isa will remain on earth for forty years, and by al-Tabarani from the hadith of 'Abdullah bin Mughaffal, 'Isa son of Mary descends, confirming Muhammad on his religion <sup>(millah)</sup>.

Imam an-Nawawi explained in his commentary on Sahih Muslim -see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&idfrom=452&idto=460&bk_no=53&ID=80)-:

> وقوله - صلى الله عليه وسلم - حكما أي ينزل حاكما بهذه الشريعة لا ينزل برسالة مستقلة وشريعة ناسخة بل هو حاكم من حكام هذه الأمة
> And his saying - may Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him - (*hakaman*) as a ruler or arbitrator, means that he descends as a person ruling based on this shari'a. And does not come down with an independent message and an abrogating shari'a, rather he is a ruler from among the rulers of this nation (Ummah).

So 'Isa will be among the rulers of this Ummah and he will not come with a new shari'a, but rather confirm it and rule based on it.

### More context and clarification of the leadership

Also note the Sahih hadith:

> What will be your state when the son of Mary descends amongst you and there will be an Imam amongst you?
> (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3449) and in Sahih Muslim:[1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3449), [2](https://sunnah.com/muslim:155e) and [3](https://sunnah.com/muslim:155f) )

Which says 'Isa will appear at the time Muslims have an imam (leader) from among them (which is a reference to al-Mahdi). Which is also confirmed in:

> I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: A section of my people will not cease fighting for the Truth and will prevail till the Day of Resurrection. He said: Jesus son of Mary would then descend and their (Muslims') commander would invite him to come and lead them in prayer, but he would say: No, some amongst you are commanders over some (amongst you). This is the honour from Allah for this Ummah.
> ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:156))

For further information on al-Mahdi you may check: [What is Sunni view regarding the savior of the world?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29305/what-is-sunni-view-regarding-the-savior-of-the-world)

The following hadith which was compiled by al-Hakim and also by abu Dawod in his [Sunan](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4285) -it should at least be linked in the post above-:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: The Mahdi will be of my stock, and will have a broad forehead a prominent nose. He will fill the earth will equity and justice as it was filled with oppression and tyranny, and he will rule for **seven years.**

Based on all the given information fatwa islamqa #[170174](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/170174/%D9%87%D9%84-%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B8%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%87%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%AD) -available in Arabic only so far- summarizes:

- At the time 'Isa () descends al-Mahdi () is the imam of the Muslims. As 'Isa will pray behind him. The reign of al-Mahdi will last 7 years.
- Then 'Isa will follow as the leader of the Muslims and fight the Dajjaal.

Al-Mubarakpuri summarizes similarly in his commentary when introducing the [first hadith](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2230) chapter on al-Mahdi -see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&idfrom=4250&idto=4255&bk_no=56&ID=1519) in his Tuhfat al-Ahwadhi in Aarbic-:

> اعلم أن المشهور بين الكافة من أهل الإسلام على ممر الأعصار أنه لا بد في آخر الزمان من ظهور رجل من أهل البيت يؤيد الدين ويظهر العدل ويتبعه المسلمون ويستولي على الممالك الإسلامية ويسمى بالمهدي
> Know that it is well known among all the people of Islam through the ages, that at the end of time a man from the household of the Prophet must appear who will support the religion, show <sup>and reestablish</sup> justice. He will be followed by the Muslims, and will take over the Islamic kingdoms, and he will be called the Mahdi.
>
> ويكون خروج الدجال وما بعده من أشراط الساعة الثابتة في الصحيح على أثره ،
> The emergence of ad-Dajjaal (the Antichrist) and what comes after him are among the signs of the Hour that are confirmed in the Sahih will be on his trail.
>
> وأن عيسى عليه السلام ينزل من بعده فيقتل الدجال أو ينزل من بعده فيساعده على قتله ويأتم بالمهدي في صلاته
> And that 'Isa, peace be upon him, descends after him and kills the Dajjaal, or descends after him, and helps him to kill him and he will follow the Mahdi as the imam in his prayers.

Comment: Thanks, for the ginormous effort,  May Allah correct your affairs. This only proves if a muslim is a proper candidate can become leader/Khalifa irrespective hes from quraysh. I mean a mujadid can become caliph of muslims.

Comment: Secondly,as per shia theology mahdi being infallible He withdraws and offers lead of prayer to jesus.... wonder what mahdi wants to convey to muslims.

Comment: Doesnt the text "abrogate jizya" help in any kind.? Since revelation has stopped and only revelation can abrogate parts of Sharia. I am assuming only Allah can abrogate any part of sharia.

Comment: @ShaikAbdullah I was expecting this question to come, but didn't want to add an explanation about this addition. In fact 'Isa would give all non-Muslims two options: Islam or fight! So Jizyah will no more be accepted. But I"d say to cover this you should ask a new question.

Comment: I meant does the text "abrogate jizya" qualify jesus as ruler?

Comment: @ShaikAbdullah it would certainly. However the more interesting question is whether this is in conflict with him not coming with a new shari'a.

Comment: I dont see the conflict. All prophets dreams are revelation. I believe Allah may abrogate jizya by dream to jesus. Or send jibril.